# SSL certificate for mail server on root domain vs wildcard on subdomain

Tags: apache, email, ssl, subdomain, wildcard

I installed a general RapidSSL certificate on my Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Apache/iRedMail server at Digital Ocean. It verifies fine in the browser and when I use RapidSSL's checker tool.

However, this server is exclusively for mail, and when I set up an account in Mail (Mac OS) or on my iPhone, etc., I have to make a security exception because it gives me the error "This root certificate is not trusted." And it shows the location as being GuangDong, China for some reason.

I spoke with a support person at eNom (where I bought the SSL certificate) and he mentioned that there might be an issue using the root domain instead of a subdomain for mail, and that I may need a wildcard certificate instead. That suggestion makes no logical sense to me.

My general question is: **Is there any difference between setting up a mail server with a general SSL certificate on the root domain, as opposed to a mailserver on a subdomain with a wildcard SSL certificate?**

Or is something wrong with my Apache configuration, perhaps?

Thanks! :)

---

***Update:***

So now I did the following:

in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

changed:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
```

To:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certificate.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/certificate.key
ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

Then in /etc/postfix/main.cf

I changed:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
```

To:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/certificate.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/intermeidate.crt
```

Then, I reboot the server. And Apache hangs, get this error:

```
root@host:~# service apache2 status
Apache2 is NOT running.
root@host:~# service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
root@host:~#
```

So, then I do this:

```
netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

result:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1464/apache2
```

Then I do this:

```
kill -9 1464
```

And Apache restarts fine after that, but roundcube won't let me log in and I can't connect to IMAP or SMTP at all.

Dovecot log says:

Nov 07 04:31:43 imap-login: Error: SSL private key file is password protected, but password isn't given

Nov 07 04:31:43 imap-login: Fatal: Couldn't parse private ssl_key

---

***Update Again:***

Everything in Dovecot is working great now. Had to do the following, since my certificate is encrypted with a password:

killall dovecot

dovecot -p

Then enter my password.

Now my problem is with Postfix, which isn't working at all. I'm assuming it doesn't like the password protected key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure dovecot to use SSL.

You have installed and configured SSL only for apache, IMAP/POP/SMTP connections are not handled by apache.

And no, there is no difference in using a domain and subdomain.

[How to setup iRedmail to use SSL](http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic4600-iredmail-support-configuring-postfix-dovecot-to-use-only-ssltls.html)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense! Still having trouble though. I edited the question.

Comment: You were right! Basically I needed to change the configs in Dovecot and Postfix. Thanks!